# Why every atom of a radioactive element, though being indistinguishable in every aspect, doesn't decay simultaneously?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, radioactivity

First of all, I know this (or, similar) question has been discussed previously here. But the discussion there couldn't help me completely getting rid of my confusion, hence this attempt.

In any radioactive sample of a particular element all the atoms involved in that accumulation of sample are obviously seem to be indistinguishable in every aspect. Then why all the atoms don't start decaying at the same time?

In practice we obviously know that they don't disintegrate simultaneously and hence my question arises that what is that x-factor that differentiates between the atom which decays first than the others?

Comment: For all we know, there is no x-factor. The atoms are ***identical***, and then one of them just up and decays, while the other continues to wait for another hour, or maybe a year. It is just blind chance, as random as it gets.

Comment: The universe is probabilistic.

Comment: While probability is entirely sufficient to explain this, also consider that not all the atoms in your sample necessarily were formed at the same time - they may be the result of several supernovae etc.

Comment: @TAR86 Atoms don't have memory of their age, that's the point. Atoms are _dumb_.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - no, it is just the nucleus that is dumb (must be something to do with the strong force?) - electrons can solve Schrodingeer's equation in their sleep...

Comment: @Mithoron I have already clarified in the beginning of the question that it is similar but not duplicate!

Comment: Not enough. Also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19564/why-does-radioactive-decay-occur

Comment: @Mithoron no offense, but I would request you to go through my question again, please.

Comment: That's only a more elaborate version of earlier one, your lack of satisfaction with earlier answers is supposed to be reason to not dupe it? Also it's not exactly about chemistry. Best answer is that's first order reaction which we don't have means to observe directly, unlike some chemical ones which were studied using femtosecond spectroscopy.